# NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ls/DocumentLS when log4j is used in another module

Tags: java, gradle, log4j

I'm facing a weird issue in a java/gradle project when I'm calling Log4J defined in a module in a different one.

Gradle dependency:

```
compile(group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-1.2-api', version: '2.1')
```

Project structure:

```
Project structure:
 -module1
  -src
   -main
    -java
     -mypackage
      -FrameworkLogger.class
    -resources
     -log4j2.xml file

 -module2
  -src
   -main
    -java
     -mypackage
      -Test.class
    -resources
```

FrameworkLoggerClass:

```
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class FrameworkLogger {

private Logger log;

public FrameworkLogger(Class className){
    this.log = LogManager.getLogger(className);
}

public void info(String message){
    log.info(message);
}

public void error(String message){
    log.error(message);
}
```

}

**log4j2.xml file is correctly configured, if I use Frameworklogger in any class from module1, is working as expected.
Module1 is recognized by module2 (declared in gradle dependecies), but when FrameworkLogger is used in any class from module2 I'm getting the following:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ls/DocumentLS
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.newDocumentBuilder(XmlConfiguration.java:85)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:137)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(XmlConfigurationFactory.java:44)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:472)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:442)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:254)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:419)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:138)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:147)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:262)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager$PrivateManager.getContext(LogManager.java:216)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:78)
    at com.db.alerttriage.tm.utils.FrameworkLogger.<init>(FrameworkLogger.java:11)
    at com.db.alerttriage.tm.cucumbersteps.workbenchpage.AlertDetailsTabSteps.<init>(AlertDetailsTabSteps.java:18)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ls.DocumentLS
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 58 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using JPMS modules? Log4j's XML support requires the JDK's java.xml module. You would need to add that to the appropriate module-info.java file.

Comment: Nope, not using it. I managed to fix it by using Log4J 1

Comment: Log4J 1 hasn’t been supported in over 6 years, has open security vulnerabilities that will never be fixed and has a bug in Java 9+.